# how can i write a oozie job depending on the success of the other job?

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, oozie-coordinator

My scenario:  I have a spark submit that is running through shell script, this spark-job will pull 7 tables from oracle to hive. i have a other script which will generate the .dat files on the basis of the imported data from oracle.

My question here : is there any chance in the oozie where if the first job succeeds only the second job should run. Please ask if you any doubts in the question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can build dependency in Oozie. Please find below the pseudo code:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="MYsimpleWF">
 <global>
  ...
</global>  
<action name=" ShellAction ">
    <shell>
        ...
        <exec>${EXEC}</exec>
        <argument>A</argument>
        <argument>B</argument>
        <file>${EXEC}#${EXEC}</file> 
    </shell>
<ok to="SecondJOB"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>
<action name="SecondJOB">
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
  ...
</shell>
<ok to="success"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>
<end name="done"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: How the above answer is satisfying dependency ? if the first job fails still it will try to run the second job right ??

Comment: In the code <ok to="SecondJOB"/>
<error to="fail"/>

Comment: If the first job will fail it will not trigger second job, it will come out. In case of success it will continue to second job.

Comment: Ok, But is there anything that i can run using some switch condition ?

Comment: Oozie creates a DAG.  The only way to go from one block to the next is how @Arvind Kumar described.  Oozie does have a switch statement.  You can find it here: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec